# Javascript - Rewriting for-loop using arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, stack, filtering, arrow-functions

How would I rewrite this using an arrow function?

Would `forEach` be the only way?

And what would be an example of an arrow function that doesn't use 
the `forEach` method.

**CODE**

```
let word = 'Bloc';

const reverseString = (str) => {

   let stack = [];

   for (let i of str) {

     stack.push(str[i]);

   }

   let reversed = '';

   for (let i of word) {

     reversed += stack.pop();

   }

  return reversed;

 }

console.log(reverseString('Bloc'));
```

Comment: You are already using an arrow function in your code, and you are using no `function`s. There are no non-arrow functions to convert to arrow functions.

Comment: Might belong to [CodeReivew](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but...what do you want to re-write here?

Comment: converting the for loops into arrow functions

Comment: But that doesn't *mean* anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) method. (In this case, reduceRight).

```js
const str = 'helloworld'; 

const newStr = str.split('').reduceRight((acc, cur) => {
    return acc + cur; 
}, ''); 

console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case for reverse String you can also follow the following code :-

```js
let word = 'Bloc';

const reverseString = (str) => {
  let reversed = '';

  // use split function of string to split and get array of letter and then call the reverse method of array and then join it .
  reversed = str.split('').reverse().join('');

  return reversed;

}

console.log(reverseString('Bloc'));
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - which is about how to avoid using for loops.